# SSL connection in Play! Framework

Tags: database, postgresql, scala, playframework

From the Play! API it follows that a database connection can be made with the following configs in application.conf:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://someDomain.com/someDatabase"
db.default.user=user
db.default.password=password
```

But when I'm throwing in `&ssl=true` in the url, it doesn't get registered and I receive the following error:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf
>   entry for host "xx.xx.xx.xx", user "user", database
>   "test&ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValida", SSL off

Are there any ways you can force Play! to use SSL connections through the .conf file?

Update: I forgot to mention that I made a successful login attempt from a console using the `psql` command. Somehow it must be Play that doesn't understand the ssl parameter.

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Postgresql reporting `database "test&ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValida"` as the database name you're trying to connect to indicates that the JDBC driver isn't taking that suffix off the end and handling it, as you need it to do.

You probably need to use `?` before the first parameter, like a normal URL:

```
jdbc://db.example.com/test?ssl=true
```

Comment: Oh dear God.. That was embarrassing. Sigh.. Thanks for the pointer araqnid!

Comment: See the heroku doc here, it explains this point under "remote connections" https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be configuration on the [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) end?

From the docs I suspect the default pg_hba.conf file being created by the db doesn't contain an entry for SSL and you need to add this manually.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the server is managed and working. I made a successful login attempt from the console using the ``psql`` command. It really should be working.. The weird thing is that it attempts to do it with SSL off, so it must be Play that fails to understand the ssl part in the URL.